# Lost passwords after running PC cleaner in firefox V21.0

Tags: windows-7, firefox, laptop

I have been really stupid and let this cleaner run. The profiles in appdata roaming are missing passwords etc. But is it possible to get them back from the appdata local profile folders?

Comment: The files were deleted.  While it MIGHT be possible to use file recovery file, if the data has been overwritten, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: I totally agree with Ramhound but, was a back up created prior to this?